# How can I tell Mobile Safari to stop remembering to never remember my password?

Tags: ios, icloud, password, keychain, mobile-safari

I've changed my mind about having Safari/iCloud Keychain never remember my password for a given website. I'd like to remove that setting and store the password, but I can't find any ability to delete/change it anywhere. I've already gone into Settings->Safari->Passwords & Autofill -> Saved Passwords, and the website in question *does not* show up in the list with a 'never' entry to delete.

How can I make Safari forget to keep forgetting this login info?

Comment: On my iphone (ios 7), sites which I have instructed Safari to never remember are listed at the bottom of the setting page that you described, and instead of the username, "not saved" is shown.

Comment: @kent yeah... Not seeing it there.

Comment: The only way I know how to do it is to directly modify the keychain database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Manually enter your username and password. Tap "Passwords" right above your keyboard. Tap "Save This Password." It still won't autofill when you first load the page, but now you can tap in the username field and hit "Autofill Password." There seems to be no way to actually reset the "Never for this site" setting. Sounds like a job for http://apple.com/feedback.

Comment: Your keyboard input must be in the "Password" field for the "Save this Password" option to be visible.

Comment: As mentioned, it'll still not autofill the username/password. See [Trooper's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/309412/218) for a solution that actually does autofill both.

Answer (score 6):

I’ve actually figured out a way to undo this. It’s klunky AF, but it works. Go to the login page you’re looking to undo this for, and tap the “passwords” label on top of the onscreen keyboard. From the pop up that appears, select “suggest new password”. Attempt to login with the new password. While you won’t successfully login with it, a login entry for the site will now be saved in your account password settings. Edit the entry with the correct information, and you’re done.

Comment: You can edit the information via Settings > Accounts & Passwords > App & Website Passwords.

Answer (score 0):

On your iPhone just clear the history of your Safari and then visit the website again... it's done, now just go back to the Safari on your iPhone and just put credentials it will ask you for if you want to save or not.